# Django HttpResponseRedirect() doesn't work - it doesn't redirect to the page

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls, django-url-reverse

I was trying to implement the function `listing(request, listId)` that when user wants to post a comment without login, it will be redirected to the login page.

This is the code of my `listing(request, listId)` in `views.py`

```py
def listing(request, listId):

    if request.method == "POST":

        if request.user.is_authenticated:
    
            # some code here to manipulate data
        else:
            HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("login"))


    return render(request, "auctions/listing.html", 
                    {
                      "listing":Listing.objects.get(pk=listId),
                      "comments": Listing.objects.get(pk=listId).itemComment.all(),
                      "bids": Listing.objects.get(pk=listId).itemBid.all(),
                      "bidCount": Listing.objects.get(pk=listId).itemBid.count(),
                      "currentPrice": currentPrice,
                      "isValidBid": True
                      }
                  )
```

Here is the `urls.py`, note that the name of login url is `"login"`

```py
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("login", views.login_view, name="login"),
    path("logout", views.logout_view, name="logout"),
    path("register", views.register, name="register"),
    path("add_listing", views.addListing, name="addListing"),
    path("listing_<int:listId>", views.listing, name="listing")
]
```

The problem is each time when I click the submit button without login, it doesn't redirect me to the login page but stays in the original page, which is not what I expect.

I also tried to replace `HttpsResponseRedirect(reverse("login"))` with `redirect("login")` and type the whole url in like `HttpsResponseRedirect("/login")`. Both of them didn't work.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that you're not returning the redirect.
it should be:

```py
return HttpResponseRedirect(...)
```

It now is still running the code to render the template, this is the only response django will see.

Comment: This is actually a silly mistake lmao. Thank you very much